# Are Halo: Combat Evolved and Minecraft compatible with Ubuntu? How to transfer files from Windows to Ubuntu?

Tags: minecraft, transfer

When installing Ubuntu, I got the **Install alongside Windows 7** option. Is there a possible way of me being able to transfer a file from my Windows 7 installation to Ubuntu? Also, are **Halo: Combat Evolved** and **Minecraft** compatible with Ubuntu?

Comment: It seems like you're asking two things here.

Comment: I am asking two things but they derived from the same situation.

Comment: No.  No they are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to your question about moving files, yes you can. Just save the file somewhere on the Windows partition and then from the Ubuntu side, browse to it in Nautilus.

Minecraft is just a Java file. Just search around this site and you'll find instructions to run it.

In order to run games meant for windows, you'll want to use Wine. As for Halo, you can see [here](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=2720) that it has a gold rating. Shoot [no pun intended] for versions 1.08 or higher since it doesn't have a CD activation bug.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu can mount your Windows 7 partition, so simply clicking and dragging from the windows partition to the ubuntu partition within ubuntu should allow you to 'transfer' the file.

Minecraft is written in JAVA and thus runs natively in almost every OS, including Ubuntu.

Halo supposedly runs [pretty well](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1986) in WINE.

Answer (score 2):

Minecraft is java based, so yes. Java is cross platform, and there is a java for Ubuntu.

Halo Combat evolved, well [WineHQ](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1986) claims that it's working with wine.

So yes on both questions.

And with transfering the files, just mount your disk and drag & drop the files.

Answer (score 2):

In response to Minecraft, the **Ubuntu Software Center** has a couple applications for launching Minecraft. I've not tried any of them, but you can see them by searching for "Minecraft".

What I found was **MC-Launcher ($2.99 USD)** and **[Mini Minecraft Launcher](http://www.news.orneodev.org/tag/miniminecraftlauncher/) ($4.00 USD)**